# How to increase max height of UITextView beyond 10000 in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a huge text to display in iOS UITextView which makes the height around 40000 but in XCode it says it cannot support size larger than 10000 by 10000.

Any solutions?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Could you break up the text and put the broken up pieces into a table view, where each cell displays a portion of the text? This would still give the effect of one long scrollable text view.

Comment: well I also have to format the text according to the expected behavior. its a terms and conditions text basically.

Comment: You should still be able to handle any formatting you need. Unless you include more details in your post, you may not get any more specific answers.

Comment: I was thinking to put multiple text views in scroll view one after the other but I don't exactly know how to do that since I'm a web developer working on iOS project for first time...

Comment: That solution would work too. Have you tried that? Do you have any code to post?

Comment: `UITextView` is already backed inside a `UIScrollView`, so you don't need to change the height of your `UITextView` to keep your entire text visible.

If you text is *really* big and, you text is ready-only, why not you use a WebView instead?

Comment: nope not yet, I was just thinking that, but I just wanted to know if there is a way to increase that size limitations of 10000. but anyways I can try that first, but I'll try your way too if it does not work

Comment: Ya thats the easiest way I could think but I'm restricted to do that

Comment: Thanks though, I'll try your solution

Comment: either use the `UILabel` that's already on the default UITableViewCell class (set the `numberOfLines` to `0`), separating your superstring by newLines giving each cell a substring, or use https://cocoapods.org/pods/DZNWebViewController with a url

Comment: Another option is to change the dimensions in code.  But of course, you're doing it wrong to begin with.  `UITextView` already allows scrolling through text.  You don't make the view large enough to display the text, you make it large enough to fit on screen, and even in the macOS world, 10Kx10K is larger than any possible screen dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: you're doing it wrong.

A `UITextView` already allows scrolling through text. You don't make the view large enough to display the text, you make it large enough to fit on screen, and even in the macOS world, 10Kx10K is larger than any possible screen dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

so many text that size  over 10000 ,I  advice you to  use UiWebview or UILable replace UITextField. I hope I can help you.

```
 -(UIWebView*)XueweiwebView {
     if (!_XueweiwebView) {
         _XueweiwebView = [[UIWebView alloc]init];
        _XueweiwebView.frame = self.tableView.frame;
         _XueweiwebView.delegate = self;
         _XueweiwebView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
        NSString* str = @"<p>here  is many text you can plae 4000 charater or more</p>";
        [_XueweiwebView loadHTMLString:str baseURL:nil];
         [self.view addSubview:_XueweiwebView];
    }
    return _XueweiwebView; 
}


    NSString* str = @"<p> place your text 40000 </p>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this would work too and its easy considering I'm a web developer; but I'm restricted to use any kind of webview, Thanks though